# Show all Collections with one button in 2.8

Tags: shortcut, collections

In 2.7, we had a button to show all the layers. In 2.8, this button is for the Pie menu. Do we still have this functionality for Collections?

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/184966/unhide-all-collections-hotkey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blender 2.8 you can isolate and iterate on each one by pressing the numbers on your keyboard, this will show only the collection that you want and hide the others, if you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> it will give you the same result. To show all the collection again press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>.

Answer (score 3):

Go the the outliner. Ensure the "Viewport Visibility" eyeball icon toggle is active.

Pick any collection in the outliner. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> once on the eye to show only it. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Left Mouse Button</kbd> again to show all collections.

Answer (score 0):

There is a dropdown in the Viewport header just for that:

[image]

Comment: I don't seem to have that button, it must have been removed at some point in the development of 2.80