# Unhide all collections hotkey?

Tags: shortcut, collections

It seems like there are only, an isolate and hide/show a single collection, hotkeys, but no show all collections hotkey. Am I missing something?

I often accidentally isolate a collection and it's a bit awkward, that you have to press undo, instead of clicking 1 twice for example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Put the mouse cursor over the Collections field and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

Comment: Now I feel really dumb.

Comment: Don't. I struggled a bit to find it too. However if you have a lot of hidden objects in your scene you don't want to unhide everytime the workaround hatinacat2000 suggested is a better way to go.

Comment: It surprises me how often the solutions to questions in Blender turn out to be so obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Make 1 new collection at the top; Drag-drop all other collections into top collection.

Answer (score 0):

I'm here because I had the same issue.  I kept accidentally hiding the collections (bar the first) by pressing 1.
Intuitively I pressed 1 again to reverse the situation.  An easy mistake, but an easy fix, I thought.
Here I find out that I need to drag my cursor over to the Outliner, then press Alt+H to reverse the mistake.
I appreciate that people have supplied the answer, but I feel Elmazz makes a good point: Please make 1 a toggle.