# How do you hide all but one object using the Outliner?

Tags: shortcut, outliner, navigation

[image: Blender 4.0.1 outliner, with the visibility "eye" icons highlighted]

How do you hide all-but-one object in the outliner? I was sure there was some modifier key you could hold when clicking on the visibility (️) icons, but none seem to work.

I've had a look in the the Preferences > Keymap, but not found such a setting.

The usual <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> for hide others and unhide all don't seem to work in the outliner.

**Edit**: I do not believe this is a duplicate of [Show all Collections with one button in 2.8](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126555/show-all-collections-with-one-button-in-2-8) since I don't want to hide or show collections, but individual objects.

**Edit 2**: My use-case is wanting to find which of many overlapping objects I need to make an edit to, so I am looking for a way to toggle visibility so only one object is visible at a time *without* changing the view in the 3D viewport. Local view is great, but it moves the camera. Selecting things in the 3D viewport usually requires moving the view. I can (and do!) select in the outliner and then use "hide others" and "unhide all" in the 3D viewport, but it's a lot of back and forth. I was hoping there's a way to tab through my objects a bit like you tab through applications in your OS of choice...

Comment: Do you know about the local view? Press the forward slash key (in 3D viewport, not outliner) and all objects should become hidden other than the active object.

Comment: I am - the local view is great for making edits to a mesh, but what I'm after is a quick way to see my objects one at a time without the viewport moving so I can find which of many overlapping objects I need to make an edit to. The local view moves the viewport, and selecting objects in the 3D viewport usually requires changing the view too. Hence looking for a way to do it in the outliner. I'll expand the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about you, but selecting the object you want to show and pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> seems to hide all objects except for the one you are selecting.

Example:https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/16pbdl4qd4bgcpgi1s8db/hideallbutone.mp4?rlkey=eencsq2xm86ni353o3nsilceh&dl=0

Comment: He said "using the Outliner" not in the 3D view. I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: Thanks, though I'm confused why his 3D view doesn't show.

Comment: Surely that's down to the app he's used to create the image of the outliner? You can also use Blender's own Window > Save Screenshot (Editor) and click on the Outliner to just save an image of the Outliner on its own without the rest of Blender's workspace. See the section in the [Manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.6/interface/window_system/topbar.html?utm_source=blender-3.6.5#window-menu).

Comment: I mean like, you could just click and drag the visibility buttons. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w6-SOA3-x4XjBLwIiBYggGOTTmCcCBwU/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: That link is requesting access, but you shouldn't put links to external files in comments anyway.

Comment: Thanks all, I am aware of local view and how to hide others and unhide all, but they only work in the 3D viewport. I was hoping there is a way to quickly hide others from the outliner so I can find which of many overlapping objects is the one I need to make an edit to.

Comment: The fastest way to do it is to probably hide all and then manually drag the visibility buttons to show them.